# Angular app's injected module's controller not getting ran

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a main App "MyApp", with its own controller and scope, i want "MyApp" to use a module "SharedModule" with its own controller and scope, but the controller for the module does not seem to be called. Does anyone know why?

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-controller="SharedModuleController">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    angular
        .module('SharedModule',[])
        .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
            // call 1st
        }])
        .controller('SharedModuleController', function($scope){
            // not called: skipped
        });

    angular
        .module('MyApp',['SharedModule'])
        .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
            // called 2nd
        }])
        .controller('MyController', function($scope){
            // called 3rd
        });
</script>
```

This is just an example code I typed to simulate a concept that represents my current long code. Syntax might not be 100% correct.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/333w1gwr/ I don't know what to tell you...

Comment: As Explosion Pills mentioned, your code works as intended. You possibly have a syntax issue with your actual code or the 'SharedModule' module is not being injected into your root app module.

Comment: It was a missing </div> .. as thanks for the answer as it directed me away from thinking my concept is wrong and got me looking in the right place.. btw, as a new user on SO, in this situation, should i remove this post or leave it?

Comment: @andyh0316 please delete the post since it would not be helpful for future users.